# Xpath Select values from one node that doesn't exist in another

Tags: xslt, xpath, muenchian-grouping, node-set

```
<my-courses>
  <courses-reqd>
     <details> 
       <subject>Math</subject>
     </details>
     <details>
       <subject>Econ</subject>
     </details>
     <details>
       <subject>Geog</subject>
     </details> 
     <details>
       <subject>Phys</subject>
     </details>
     <detail>
       <subject>Zool</subject>
     </details>
  </courses-reqd>
  <courses-taken>
    <details> 
      <subject>Math</subject>
    </details>
    <details>
      <subject>Econ</subject>
    </details>
    <detail>
      <subject>Zool</subject>
    </details>
  </courses-taken>
```

I have provided sample XML and want to know how to get the values the are not in the    courses-taken but are in the courses-reqd by using XPATH. In the case provided, the answer would be Geog and Phys as they do not exist in course-taken.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="my-courses\courses-reqd | not(my-courses\courses-taken)"/>
```

Is this possible and if so, how would I go abouts doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer here is to do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
   select="/my-courses/courses-reqd/detail
                [not(subject = /my-courses/courses/taken/details/subject)]" />
```

A better (more efficient) approach is to use keys.

This would be added towards the top of your XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="kTaken" match="courses-taken//subject" use="."/>
```

And then this would be used in one of your templates:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
         select="/my-courses/courses-reqd/detail[not(key('kTaken', subject))]" />
```

When this XSLT is run on your sample input (after the sample input has been corrected to consistently use elements named "details" and not "detail":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kTaken" match="courses-taken//subject" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
          select="/my-courses/courses-reqd/details[not(key('kTaken', subject))]" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="details">
    <course>
      <xsl:value-of select="subject"/>
    </course>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<root>
  <course>Geog</course>
  <course>Phys</course>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried it and it works. I have added a subj-no tag to each of the subjects

How would I code it if it is looking for two keys for instance, subject and subj-no. I have tried concatenating this by doing the following: 

    <xsl:apply-templates
   select="/my-courses/courses-reqd/details
                [not(concat(subject, subj-no) = concat(/my-courses/courses-taken/details/subject, /my-courses/courses-taken/details/subject-no))]" />

However, I have had no luck. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?